# How can I buffer an unbuffered ResultSet in ZF2 zend-db?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db

My `Atlas` class performs a recursive data exploration given a non-contiguous but sequential set of `col1` values, read from MySQL `table1` beginning with `$startingVal`. Limit `$totalVal` is a throttle for work units during any given session. On each recursion, `Atlas` will retrieve between zero and eight (0-8) rows from a different table.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException'
>        with message 'Row count is not available in unbuffered result sets.'
>        in /path/vendor/Zend/zend-db/src/Adapter/Driver/Mysqli/Result.php:316
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /path/vendor/Zend/zend-db/src/ResultSet/AbstractResultSet.php(65):
>        Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Mysqli\Result->count()
>       #1 /path/vendor/Zend/zend-db/src/Adapter/Adapter.php(195):
>        Zend\Db\ResultSet\AbstractResultSet->
>        initialize(Object(Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Mysqli\Result))
>       #2 /path/modules/Flightplan/src/Flightplan/Atlas.php(110): 
>        Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter->query('SELECT col1...', Array)
>       #3 /path/utility.php(46):
>   Flightplan\Atlas->shoulder_routes('30000001', '1')
>       #4 {main} thrown in /path/vendor/Zend/zend-db/src/Adapter/Driver/Mysqli/Result.php
>        on line 316

If I am reading the error and Zend source correctly, `Adapter` is initializing an `AbstractResultSet` (buffering by default) with a `Mysqli\Result` resource (non buffering by default), and immediately after, tries to count it, which throws the error. This is happening the during my first query through Adapter, before recursion.

## AbstractResultSet.php

```
public function initialize($dataSource)
{
    // reset buffering
    if (is_array($this->buffer)) {
        $this->buffer = array();
    }

    if ($dataSource instanceof ResultInterface) {
        $this->count = $dataSource->count();         // line 65
```

## Atlas.php:

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;

public function __construct( array $configArray = null ){
    ...
    $this->configArray = $configArray;
    $this->adapter = new Adapter( $this->configArray );
}
public function shoulder_routes( $startingVal, $totalVal ){
    ...
    $result = $this->adapter->query( 'SELECT col1 FROM table1 
        WHERE col1 >= ? LIMIT ?', array( $startingVal, $totalVal ));  // line 110
    $result->buffer(); // ADDED AFTER 1st error occurrence 
    ...
}
```

I added `$result->buffer();` which is unfortunately useless since the error occurs before execution returns to `Atlas`.

## How can I rectify this?

1. `Mysqli\Result` CAN be set to buffer at initialization. Do I extend `Result` with buffering on by default, and would I specify that in `Atlas`, like:

`$this->adapter = new Adapter( $this->configArray,null,new MyMysqliResult() );`

*Edit: Supplying a ResultInterface as a parameter to Adapter threw an error, as Adapter is expecting a ResultSet. However, it may be possible to extend AbstractResultSet so that IT calls $result->buffer() before calling $result->count() on the ResultSet passed to it from Adaper\Driver\Mysqli...*

2. (I think) I read that Zend\Adapter PDO_Mysql driver/platform/result DOES buffer by default. Is there any reason not to switch to PDO?

*Edit: Switching to PDO_Mysql Adapter\Driver resulted in following error, which I imagine may be resolved if I prepare a driver-supplied statement*

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1'' at line 1' in /path/vendor/Zend/zend-db/src/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Statement.php:239

3. I have also seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320790/zf2-how-to-do-this-simple-query-with-zend-db) where `result->getResource()->fetchAll();` may help later in `Atlas` but again the error is occurring before I get this chance.

What am I missing? Thanks -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After coming and going from this problem and project for a few months, I stumbled upon an answer [here](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Row-count-is-not-available-in-unbuffered-result-sets-td4655689.html) which lead me to the same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702870/row-count-is-not-available-in-unbuffered-result-sets-with-zend-table-gateway).

```
    $config => array(
       ...
      'options' => array(
        'buffer_results' => true,
    ),
```

I was looking for this kind of answer, and obviously stared too hard.